# Fazer uma busca com filtro em PHP em multiplas tabelas

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, algoritmo-de-busca

Eu preciso fazer uma busca com filtros por exemplo ESPECIALIDADE > CIDADE e então mostrar resultado da busca

segue meu código:

```
                    <?php if ($specialty != null && $city != null) { ?>                                         
                <?php 
        $querySelectSpecialty = "SELECT * FROM specialty WHERE specialtyname = '$specialty'";
        $resultSelectSpecialty = mysqli_query($conn,$querySelectSpecialty);
        $numresults = mysqli_num_rows($resultSelectSpecialty);
        
        if ($numresults >= 1) {
                
                while($rowSelectSpecialty = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSelectSpecialty)){
                $id_medico = $rowSelectSpecialty['iddoc'];
                $especialidade = ucfirst($rowSelectSpecialty['specialtyname']);
                $tipo = $rowSelectSpecialty['tipo'];
                    
                $querySelectLocation = "SELECT * FROM endereco_doc WHERE city = '$city'";
                $resultSelectLocation = mysqli_query($conn,$querySelectLocation);
                
                while($rowSelectLocation = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSelectLocation)){
                $id_medico_location = $rowSelectLocation['iddoc'];
                $cep = $rowSelectLocation['cep'];
                $rua = $rowSelectLocation['rua'];
                $numero = $rowSelectLocation['numero'];
                $bairro = $rowSelectLocation['bairro'];
                $complemento = $rowSelectLocation['complemento'];
                $cidade = $rowSelectLocation['city'];
                $uf = $rowSelectLocation['uf'];
                $id_medico = $rowSelectLocation['iddoc'];
                
                
                $querySelectProfile = "SELECT * FROM doc WHERE iddoc = '$id_medico_location'";
                $resultSelectProfile = mysqli_query($conn,$querySelectProfile);
                $numResultProfile = mysqli_num_rows($resultSelectProfile);
                
                while($rowSelectProfile = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSelectProfile)){
                $nome = $rowSelectProfile['nome'];
                $sobrenome = $rowSelectProfile['sobrenome'];
                $n_crm = $rowSelectProfile['n_crm'];
                $uf_crm = $rowSelectProfile['uf_crm'];
                
                 ?>
                <div class="result-search-box">
                    <div class="result-search-header">
                        <div class="image">
                            <div class="profile-image-filter" style="background-image:url('http://localhost/images/no-image-profile.jpg');"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3><span id="first-name-filter"><?php echo "$nome"; ?></span><span> </span><span id="last-name-filter"><?php echo "$sobrenome"; ?></span></h3>
                            <p><span id="specialty-filter"><?php echo "$especialidade"; ?></span><span> / CRM </span><span id"crm-number-filter"><?php echo "$n_crm"; ?></span><span> </span><span id="crm-uf-filter"><?php echo "$uf_crm"; ?></span></p>
                            <span id="avaliations">
                                <img id="avaliation-stars" src="http://localhost/images/no-stars.png">
                                <a id="profile-result-avaliation-link" href="#"><span><span id="number-avaliations">0</span> opiniões</span></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="profile-address">
                        <div class="profile-address icon">
                            <span id="title-city"><?php echo "$cidade"; ?></span><br>
                            <div id="address-full">
                                <span id="address"><?php echo "$rua"; ?></span><span>, </span><span id="addressnumber"><?php echo "$numero"; ?></span><span>, </span><span id="complement"><?php echo "$complemento"; ?></span><span> - </span><span id="district"><?php echo "$bairro"; ?></span><span>, </span><span id="city"><?php echo "$cidade"; ?></span><span> - </span><span id="uf"><?php echo "$uf"; ?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-address-contact">
                            <div class="profile-whatsapp btn">
                                <a class="btnlight" id="profile-search-result" href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><button id="btn-profile-search-result">Ver perfil</button></a>
                                <a id="whatsapp-profile-search" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=554731838200&text=Ol%C3%A1" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><button id="btn-whatsapp-contact">Chamar no Whatsapp</button></a>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php 
                  } // while resultSelectProfile
                  } // while resultSelectProfile
                } // while resultSelectSpecialty
                  
                  } else {
                    
                    echo "Nada encontrado nos parâmetros informados.";
                    
                }
                
        } else {
            
            echo "Obrigatório indicar a Especialidade e Cidade.";
            
        }
                ?>
```

Acontece que ele está retornando varios resultados e multiplicando eles, o correto era aparecer apenas os resultados de acordo os filtros e sem multiplicação de dados retornado

É um while dentro de outro, pois um chama um select do banco de dados

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Carlos você pode atualizar sua pergunta com um exemplos dos dados que tem em cada tabela por favor? e algum print? Vai ficar mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Parece que você esta buscando várias vezes o mesmo valor de `iddoc`. Como `$specialty` e `$city` não podem ser nulos para iniciar a busca, você pode eliminar metade esses while dentro de while. `SELECT * FROM specialty, endereco_doc WHERE specialty.specialtyname = '{$specialty}' AND endereco_doc.city = '{$city}'`

Comment: Junior, me ajudou, precisava disto, muito obrigado! resolvido.

Comment: Por nada, Carlos. Vou postar como resposta e marque como aceita, por favor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parece que você esta buscando várias vezes o mesmo valor de `iddoc`.

Como `$specialty` e `$city` não podem ser nulos para iniciar a busca, você pode elimitar metade esses while dentro de while.

*Ex: se existirem 200 registros, vai executar o laço interno 200 vezes, ficando péssimo em questão de performance.*

Note que no `SELECT` eu usei `AND`, que significa que as duas condições precisam ser atendidas. Caso contrário, você pode usar `OR`, para uma ou outra ser atendida.

Existem outras formas de fazer a consulta em duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, mas acredito que esta seja mais simples pelo teu código. Tente:

```
SELECT * FROM specialty, endereco_doc WHERE specialty.specialtyname = '{$specialty}' AND endereco_doc.city = '{$city}'
```

Comment: Resolveu! Thanks'

Comment: No caso, eu quero fazer paginação com estes resultados, é possível com diversos whiles?

Comment: Clique na seta à esquerda para marcar a resposta como aceita. É possível sim, de uma pesquisada em paginação, mesmo com os whiles não é complicado. Se encontrar problemas, só abrir uma nova pergunta com as dúvidas.

Comment: feito, por favor, vote na minha pergunta , estão colocando -3 e ninguém me ajuda, isto ta impedindo de criar novas questions

Comment: Votado. Voce pode usar um recurso para criar paginação em JS. Veja https://datatables.net/